# Passing Variable to make from the command line?

Tags: makefile

All,

I'm trying to pass variables to make from the command line.  My command is below

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/my_dir/bin/arm-openwrt-linux-g++
```

The error I received is

```
g++: error: arm: No such file or directory
```

But the file 'arm-openwrt-linux-g++' does exist.

I think the problem is I need to pass varibale to sub-make files.  Can some help with an example of how to pass varialbes to sub-makefile from the command-line.  I have tried using the -e and export options for make, but can't seen to get anything to work.

Thanks

Content of makefile:

```
# GNU Make solution makefile autogenerated by Premake
# Type "make help" for usage help

ifndef config
config=debug
endif
export config

    PROJECTS := json openjaus

.PHONY: all clean help $(PROJECTS)

all: $(PROJECTS)

json: 
@echo "==== Building json ($(config)) ===="
@${MAKE} --no-print-directory -C .build -f json.make

openjaus: json
    @echo "==== Building openjaus ($(config)) ===="
    @${MAKE} --no-print-directory -C .build -f openjaus.make
```

Comment: There's no way for us to guess what's going on in your Makefiles if we can't see them.

Comment: Is the content of file necessary in order to evaluate if the command-line is correct?  My basic question is I'm passing variables properly.  I will provide the content of the file if necessary.

Comment: There is nothing obvious wrong with how you are passing them; that's why my comment.  Something is happening within your Makefile(s) to trigger that error, something that is not obvious just from the invocation you showed.

Comment: I have added the content of the makefie to the original post. Thx

Comment: Still no indication of where things are going wrong; you *do* need to arrange for your settings to be passed to the sub-`make`s though, *probably* by explicit invocation (`${MAKE} ARCH=${ARCH} ...`).

Comment: You do NOT explicitly need to add variable assignments to the submake command line.  As long as you use $(MAKE) or ${MAKE} to invoke the sub-make, the sub-make will inherit all the command line variable assignments of the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your problem is not related to sending variables over the command line.

Your problem is that in one of the makefiles in your sub-directories, which you haven't shown us, you're using the variable $(ARCH) in an incorrect way such that the expansion of the command line is not a legal `g++` command line.

Based on the error message, most likely you're adding a space somewhere where it shouldn't be, so instead of something like `-fmarch=arm` you're getting `-fmarch= arm`.  Obviously this is just an example because you didn't provide nearly enough information.

One other note: we can't know how your makefiles work but typically makefiles that support a variable like CROSS_COMPILE expect it to be set to just the prefix of the cross-compilation command; in your case it would be `CROSS_COMPILE=/my_dir/bin/arm-openwrt-linux-`.  But, your makefiles might be different.

When asking questions, it's best to if you don't immediately jump to a guess about what the answer is.  First describe the problem, and that includes showing the error line *as well as* a few lines before it.  For example in this case you're getting an error from `g++` so the command line that make printed out showing you how it invoked `g++` would have helped greatly.

Once you've given the underlying detail, then if you think you have an idea about what the problem is go ahead and suggest it, and/or ask about it.

If you provide the rule that invokes `g++` and/or the output from make showing the `g++` command line, then we can help more.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks all!  Working on editing the original post to add more details.

Comment: Problem solved. The issue was rules in submake files were using host g++ instead of target g++.  Many thanks to everyone who commented!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think needs to happen:

You need to make sure that your sub-makefiles actually respect the `$(ARCH)` and `$(CROSS_COMPILE)` variables. Are they also generated by Premake? If so, is that how it handles cross-compilation? Check the docs.

In my test (below), I found that variables set on the command line are propagated to sub-makes, which makes me think that your sub-makefiles aren't respecting `$(ARCH)`:

Makefile:

```
a:
        $(MAKE) -C z
```

z/Makefile:

```
a:
        @echo "MAKE=$(MAKE)"
        @echo "ARCH=$(ARCH)"
```

Running `make` with no arguments:

```
$ make
make -C z
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/foo/test/z'
MAKE=make
ARCH=
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/foo/test/z'
```

Running `make ARCH=bar`:

```
$ make ARCH=bar
make -C z
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/foo/z/z'
MAKE=make
ARCH=bar
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/foo/z/z'
```